# Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyName' in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, cross-site

I know there might be some questions related to this, but that was not useful for me. So here what is my issue.

I am getting error as

*Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyName' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

When I added the line

```
encoderType="AntiXssEncoder, AssemblyName"
```

in web.config file for *httpRunTime* attribute. Why I am getting these error i dont know.

Also I took the reference from [here.](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

You’ll should replace `AssemblyName` with the name of your assembly.